# VBA Excel Copy and paste values to new work with set range after last row

Tags: excel, vba

copying and pasting range of cells but only values to new workbook after last line. My copy worksheet data range starts at o3 and goes to r100. data will change. the new work book where i want to start pasting just the values starts at cell m13. by clicking button i want pull new data under a blank line.

I have researched code that either does copy and paste to different workbooks or copying to last row. but not both.

```
Sub xtrnsf_to_other_wrkbook()

'Find the last used row in both sheets and copy and paste data below existing data.

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long

  'Set variables for copy and destination sheets

  Set wsCopy = Workbooks("LP sort2.xlsm").Worksheets("Chalks")
  Set wsDest = Workbooks("PC.xlsm").Worksheets("Planner's Checklist")

  '1. Find last used row in the copy range based on data in column A

  lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row

  '2. Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in column A

  'Offset property moves down 1 row
  lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Offset(2).Row

  '3. Copy & Paste Data  
     wsCopy.Range("O3:R).Copy _
       wsDest.Range("M" & lDestLastRow)


End Sub
```

My copy worksheet data range starts at O3 and goes to r100. data will change. the new work book where i want to start pasting just the values starts at cell M13. by clicking button i want pull new data under a blank line.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the copy line as you left out the end of the source range.

Paste special will copy the values not the formulae.

```
 wsCopy.Range("O3:R" & lCopyLastRow).Copy 
 wsDest.Range("M" & lDestLastRow).pastespecial xlvalues
```

Comment: i have tried that but nothing is happening? also the copying range has formulas. how do i tell it just to grab the data.

Comment: Amended - try it now.

Comment: That code will copy the value so the issue is elsewhere. Time for you to do some debugging!

Comment: awesome. i figured it out. but my problem is that everytime i hit the button i get the right result after 136 blank lines. i think this has to do with my range that i am copying. Is there any way around it or is is because my range has formulas?

Comment: What was the problem? Do you have rows of formulas which are returning empty strings? If so, it might be easiest to paste them in and then delete blank rows.

Comment: recopied your fix. but i tried on a product that doesnt use formulas to calculate cells and it works amazing. so not sure how i am going to tackle the issue of blank cells on the other product.